# How can I listen for terminal input while gulp.watch() is running?

Tags: gulp

In Gulp, I can have the watch process wait for file changes, but I also want to be able to *listen* for terminal input. For instance, the gulp-nodemon server can listen for "rs" being typed into the terminal and restart the server.

As an example, I would like to be able to create a watcher that will listen for "rb" to run a task that will rebuild the entire package (since file changes will initiate more specific tasks).

gulp-nodemon already proves it can be done, I'm wondering if anyone knows of a package or method that does this independently or configurably.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is the [`readline`](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html) module which comes with nodejs itself. It let's you listen for incoming data from `process.stdin`.

Here's a simple example that listens for `rb` (followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd>) and then executes the `rebuild` task:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var readline = require('readline');

gulp.task('scripts', function() {
  //...
});

gulp.task('rebuild', function() {
  //...
});

gulp.task('watch', function() {
  gulp.watch('src/**/*.js', ['scripts']);

  var rl = readline.createInterface({input:process.stdin});
  rl.on('line', function(line) {
    if (line === 'rb') {
      gulp.start('rebuild');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I needed.